# Is there a need for my own client to interface with my REST API through OAuth?

Tags: api, rest, authentication, oauth

Currently we have a REST API and a client, where the client authenticates the user once through HTTPS and receives an access-token. Then for each request that requires authentication, the client creates an HMAC from the request body with the URL and query string and a shared secret between the server and client. Is there any need for me to take this further and implement OAuth between my own client - API?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be performing authentication in an OAuth(v1.0a) like way already. However I would recommend you include a timestamp and a nonce in your HMAC creation and check these in your API to prevent replay attacks.